# How to make web farm work on MVC application?

Tags: model-view-controller, web-farm

How to make web farm work on MVC application? at least a full example from A to Z

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used web farm framework 1.1 to my web farm controller,
then I configure to web server for my farm .

this video shows how to make configuration for web farm 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HSvbjfsitmU